# Illustrator Pattern Brush Question

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I made a pattern brush from a pattern I want to follow a path, it mostly works fine expect that the bottom of the pattern does not follow the upper section which is what I am aiming for.

Picture:

[image]
Second picture here: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/112467995/pattern%202.PNG

The picture of the original pattern: the pattern brush being applied to the path and below is what I want to accomplish (you will notice that what I want is for the bottom to follow the top. IE. if its a shallow wave on the top, its a shallow wave on the bottom so the pattern matches on both the top and bottom)

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I really don't understand what you're trying to do or what's going on in your screenshot

Comment: See: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/112467995/pattern%202.PNG maybe you'd understand that better.

Comment: Still not really clear what is the problem. What happens when you apply your brush to the shape? What is your question?

Comment: @Luciano It applies and follows the shape but I want the bottom side of it to follow the top. Basically I have a wave shape and I want the top and bottom to match each other.

Comment: So you basically want the bottom edge to be flipped? So top and bottom sized are identical? Pattern Brushes won't do that. You'll need to use separate paths and join them manually.

Comment: @Scott Yes that is what I want to accomplish. I've guessed that there's a possibility that I'll have to do it manually considering that I couldn't find any information on this. Thanks anyways.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you are looking for:

In the pattern brush settings you can see options on how your pattern behaves in:

- Side Line
- Outer Corner
- Inner Corner
- Start Line
- End Line

[image]

As far as I can tell, you only have the Side Line set in your brush. Set your Outer/Inner Corner how you want it to behave and there you have it.

### [Here is a quick Youtube tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LHANgr35HzA) on how to create a Pattern Brush with Outer Corners.

Comment: I don't think you've understood what I want to do, its not a corner issue, its how the pattern is following the path that's the issue. On the top its following it fine, but then on the bottom I want it to mirror what it did on the top so the pattern will become symmetrical.

Comment: @EzCrazy I don't think that is possible as you put it. The one way I can think of doing this is actually taking the upper half of your design, duplicating it and then flipping it (mirroring it) to be exactly the same.

Comment: I've considered that, it must be possible tough as I've seen a similar design done by a company.